# Replace a key for an external mouse

Tags: autohotkey

I have an external mouse which also register a HID keyboard in Device Manager. One of its button shows start menu. I want to replace it with mouse click. Since I also have an inbuilt keyboard I don't want to replace its start button. I want to replace start button from the external mouse

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `#InstallKeybdHook` and look in the KeyHistory when you have pressed the button!

This can atleast tell you if your mouse button has the same virtual key code or scan code as the built-in keyboards key

This is a step by step guide http://ahkscript.org/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys